# Understanding Django Versions on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, gunicorn

I am developing a web-app using Digital Oceans "one-click Django droplet".

I noticed I am getting some error messages because I wrote the original code locally on my PC using Python 3.6 and Django 2.2. 
(The error message from Django is `cannot import 'include'`, which I've read is because `include` is Django 2.0 and above)

On the Console when I type `python -m django --version` it returns `1.11.20`
However, when I type `python3 -m django --version` it returns `2.2`.

So my question is: How do I ensure that my django app is running on python 3 and Django 2.2?
Do I have to start gunicorn differently?

In case readers haven't used Digital Oceans "one-click Django droplet" : It utilizes gunicorn, NGINX, and ubuntu.

UPDATE:
Here is actual error I am getting:

```
Internal Server Error: /

ImportError at / cannot import name include

Request Method: GET Request URL: http://example.com/ Django 
Version: 1.11.20 Python Executable: /usr/bin/python Python Version: 2.7.15 
Python Path: ['/home/django/django_project', ‘/home/django/django_project’, 
‘/usr/bin’, ‘/usr/lib/python2.7’, ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu’, ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk’, ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old’, 
‘/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload’, ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages’, 
‘/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages’] Server time: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 19:39:06 
+0000 Installed Applications: ['django.contrib.admin',
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Since your machine has 2 versions of python, you should first uninstall `python 2.7` version of `gunicorn` and then install the `python 3` version of `gunicorn`.

```
# Remove the gunicorn for Python 2.7
pip uninstall gunicorn

# Install the gunicorn for Python 3
pip3 install gunicorn

# Restart gunicorn
service gunicorn restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I did what you suggested, still showing that it is using python 2 and Django 1.. 
I updated my post with the actual error message